# Bootstrap Tabs With Angular 2 Application

Tags: angular

**Background**

I have been using `ng2-tabs` in my application but tonight when I try and run it I get errors complaining about a conflict of `components`.

Even if I remove all my code and put a few lines of the example code from the page they have on npm it still throws errors. Looking for a solution I found that they changed to NGX-tabs so I updated. This did not help.

**Question**

Is there any reason `ngx-tabs` would be breaking my app due to a new release? I am not able to make much sense of the error. Although it seems straightforward. I do not understand what is wrong.

**Examples**

*Error*

> Template parse errors:↵More than one component matched on this
>   element.↵Make sure that only one component's selector can match a
>   given element.↵Conflicting components: TabsetComponent,Tabset ("↵    [ERROR ->]↵        ↵
>   ↵"):
>   AsideComponent@1:4"

What I do not get, is why it keeps complaining about the selector. I am not aware of any of my selectors overlapping in any components.

*The html part of my components,*

```
<aside class="aside-menu">
    <tabset> // error on tabset but app runs when I remove this block.
        <tab>
            <template tabHeading><i class="fa fa-list"></i>
            </template>
        </tab>
     </tabset>  // end of tabset
</aside>
```

*My component.ts*

```
import { Component }            from '@angular/core';
import { Router }               from '@angular/router';
import { Auth }                 from './../services/auth.service';
import {TabsModule}             from "ngx-tabs";

@Component({
    selector: 'application-aside',
    templateUrl: './aside.component.html'
})
export class AsideComponent {
       constructor( private router: Router, private auth: Auth  ) { }

}
```

**Resources**

Link to the new [NGX-TABS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-tabs) which I assume we are supposed to use now and stop the old which can be found [here - NG2-TABS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-tabs)

If anyone has any input I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Did you try https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabs? This project has excellent tabs implementation (alongside with many other components!) for Angular + Bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks man I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

**in app.module.ts** just add 
 `import { Ng2BootstrapModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';`
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    Ng2BootstrapModule.forRoot(),..}]

and **in your home.component.ts**:
 `import { TabsModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap';`

 **and in home.component.html :**

```
 <div>
      <tabset>
        <tab heading="Basic title" id="tab1">Basic content</tab>
        <tab heading="Basic Title 1">Basic content 1</tab>
        <tab heading="Basic Title 2">Basic content 2</tab>
      </tabset>
    </div>
```

**in system.js:**

```
 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap': 'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ngx-bootstrap.umd.js',
'moment'                    :                       'npm:ng2-bootstrap/node_modules/moment/moment',
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is still reference to the old ng2-tabs in your node_modules folder. Try deleting the `node_modules` folder and re-install (npm install). Also make sure you have your package.json updated.